# Install4j two Progress Bars in One Screen

Tags: java, progress-bar, install4j

In my Projekt i want to show 2 Progress Bars in One Screen during the installation. I figured out that it is possible to add more than one Progress Bars into a Screen.

But how can i call each one please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind the progress bar to the default progress information that is available for a screen, it only makes sense to add one progress bar component, because only the first one will be used.

You can set the progress manually on multiple components from a script, though.

```
JProgressBar progressBar = (JProgressBar)formEnvironment
    .getFormComponentById("123")
    .getConfigurationObject();
progressBar.setValue(35);
```

In the above code snippet, a progress bar component with ID 123 is set to 35%.